# How to mute mic in Skype using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, skype

I'm using the normal skype, not skype for business, I'm using windows 10 mostly when doing skype calls and sometimes ubuntu 16.04, I'm required to mute my mic whenever someone speaks in meetings.

Is there a shortcut to toggle the mic on and off when doing skype meetings?

Comment: Similar questions are 9 years old, tried many, nothing worked

Comment: Would help if you specified what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12025/what-are-keyboard-shortcuts-and-how-do-i-use-them-in-skype):

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
- macOS: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: So the first one is not a capital m?

Comment: No, just the M key. That's how keyboard shortcuts are usually specified in the non-Emacs/vim world.